# Can someone please explain these files? defaultdws.aspx, default.aspx, ONET.xml and elements.xml

Tags: custom, site-template

I am using sharepoint 2010 and VS2010.

I have implemented this tutorial for creating a custom web template and it WORKS, Yeahhhhh:

http://usmanmughal.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/how-to-create-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010-using-feature/

but I want to know what these files means:

1. defaultdws.aspx
2. default.aspx
3. ONET.xml
4. elements.xml

Can someone explain these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Onet.xml**

> The global Onet.xml file defines list templates for hidden lists, list
>   base types, a default definition configuration, and modules that apply
>   globally to the deployment. Each Onet.xml file in a subdirectory of
>   the %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates directory can define navigational
>   areas, list templates, document templates, configurations, modules,
>   components, and server email footers that are used in the site
>   definition to which it corresponds.

[Definition of ONET.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474369%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**elements.xml**

This xml file defines the element of a feature, you can have more then one element file in a feature but with different names, this file doesn't have to be named as elements but you reference it in feature.xml.

**defaultdws.aspx & default.aspx**

These are default pages used by web template, I couldn't find out any documentation on it.

Looking at questions you keep asking, I would recommend you to go through

[Site Types: WebTemplates and Site Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms434313%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

But in short, WebTemplates are based on site definitions, if you are creating a site definition you can create it from scratch but if you are creating a web template it has to be based on a site definition as described in this picture below,

[image]

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff408392%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know now that if I would like to define some list, it must be declared in the ONET.XML. But where can I add some list in some webpart zone? Is it in the default.aspx or defaultdws.aspx ?

Comment: in module, check this link out and figure out how they setting up zone for webpart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586611(v=office.11).aspx